animate the center of the geometry
There is a balloon with physical properties, it flies up (physics of clothes).But its geometry center is not moving. Because of this, I can't bind another object to it. Please help me. Link through the parents , but in this case make the dynamic center of the geometry

You can parent object A to 3 (or 1) vertices of object B: Select object A, shift select object B, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices of object B, press CtrlP > Make Vertex Parent. Object A should follow object B when it will move:

